# SQL запрос с вычислениями по таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо написать SQL запрос, который найдёт все сессии, в течение которых пользователь делал домашнее задание перед уроком, то есть совершил последовательность действий:

1. 0 или более раз заходил на любые страницы;
2. зашел на rooms.homework-showcase (раздел со списком домашних
   заданий);
3. 0 или более раз заходил на любые страницы;
4. зашел на rooms.view.step.content (страница домашнего задания);
5. 0 или более раз заходил на любые страницы;
6. зашел на rooms.lesson.rev.step.content (страница урока с
   преподавателем);
7. 0 или более раз заходил на любые страницы.

   [image: исходные данные]

Сессией называется активность пользователя, в которой между последовательными действиями проходит менее одного часа. Сессия начинается в момент первого из этих действий и заканчивается через час после последнего из них.
Результатом должна стать выгрузка сессий вида: <идентификатор-пользователя>,<дата-время начала сессии>,<дата-время окончания сессии>.

Comment: Не мучайте SQL он не для этого, решайте задачу на ином ЯП например php или на чем вы делаете вывод информации....

Comment: *Сессией называется активность пользователя, в которой между последовательными действиями проходит менее одного часа.* ЛЮБОГО действия? или только того, что соответствует п.п. 2, 4 или 6?

Comment: Зачем это делать на SQL. Лишняя морока. Лучше возьмите и вытащить данные (по id_user, например), а потом уже с ними делайте что вам нужно.

Comment: это реально сделать на сиквеле? В какую сторону глянуть? Думал про cte+dense_rank+какие то функции в результирующем наборе. Но как это все реализовать по данному алгоритму понять не могу